# define custom WHMCS invoice status

Tags: whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

I need to create a custom invoice status for "Disputed" payments.

I found an [article](https://whmcs.community/topic/273629-new-invoice-status/) that said to just modify the status column in the DB table 'tblinvoices' with the desired status, but doing this doesn't register that as a status in the sense that the invoice PDF would show "DISPUTED" instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAA1l.png) and the admin view of the invoice looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWx64.png) (note the upper right-hand corner where it would normally say the status like PAID, UNPAID, DRAFT, etc. is blank) and the client view of the invoice looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfay7.png) (note the upper right-hand corner where it would normally say the status like PAID, UNPAID, DRAFT, etc. is blank) and lastly the invoice list (overall, not on the client page) shows the status as unrecognised as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQhdD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Things are not displayed properly cuz of lack of language translates. You should add proper translations for newly created status in language files for user and administrator in your WHMCS installation. https://developers.whmcs.com/languages/overrides/